# GIMP - Alpha to Color

Tags: colors, transparency, gimp

I have created a simple square using GIMP which color is a shade of blue (#07192c). I lowered the opacity on this square a bit, and realized I like the shade of blue which was now created from lowering the opacity.

My question is, does GIMP have a function which allows you to select (like the eyedropper) the color of a transparent layer? I've searched but can only find 'color to alpha' which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: It would be better if you'd upload an example picture here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can activate the Sample merged option of the Color Picker tool. This will pick the color as it is shown in the image composition.

This setting is available in the tool options for the color picker:

[image: Color Picker tool options]

Comment: I can't tell what's going on here...Daniel Denielecki's answer worked great for me, btw (GIMP ver. 2.8.18).

Comment: The question, at least as I understood it, is about picking a color that is a combination of the color something has and its opacity, presumably over a differently colored background.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Layer** -> **Transparency** -> **Remove Alpha Channel**
2. **Colours** -> **Map** -> **Colour Exchange...**